# How do I find the sum of the squared residuals for every iterations of the parameters in scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

In my program for finding the parameters of a function, `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` gives the optimal values no problem.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = pd.read_csv('at_5.csv', index_col='index')
x_data = np.array(data['x'])
y_data = np.array(data['y'])

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, c='blue')


def log_function(x, k, h, xo, a, ang, gamma):
    return k * np.log(((((x - xo) - a * math.cos(ang)) ** 2) + (h - a * math.sin(ang)) ** 2) /
                        ((((x - xo) + a * math.cos(ang)) ** 2) + (h + a * math.sin(ang)) ** 2)) + gamma


guess = [75,  # k
         80,  # h
         550,  # xo
         25,  # a
         math.radians(10),  # angle
         0
         ]
guesser = log_function(x_data, guess[0], guess[1], guess[2], guess[3], guess[4], guess[5])
plt.plot(x_data, guesser, color='green')

popt, cov = curve_fit(log_function, x_data, y_data, p0=guess, maxfev=10000)
print(cov)
a, b, c, d, e, f = popt
print(f'''K = {a}, h = {b}, Xo = {c}, a = {d} and angle = {math.degrees(e)}, gamma = {f}''')

y_model = log_function(x_data, a, b, c, d, e, f)


plt.plot(x_data, y_model, color='red')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('V(X)')
plt.legend(['Data', 'Guess', 'Matched Data'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

However, I would also like to know what are the sum of the squared residuals for every iterations of the parameters. Is there any way to know it, or at least know the different iterations of the parameters the function ran through.

I did try scouring through the internet first, no answers. I did look into the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.2/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L554). I couldn't find anything with my limited knowledge in programming. If it is given within the source, please point me in its direction.

Comment: What do you mean by 'every iterations of the parameters'?

Comment: yes, by every iterations of the parameters. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I think you mean at every iteration of the solver as it converges.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. As the function runs, it changes the parameters to optimize the results based on the sum of squared residuals. I would like to know what were the parameters chosen for a, b, c, d, e and f in every iteration and its sum of squared residuals. jared has given a solution for showing the residuals. I would like to know on how the function determines how much the parameters change for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in way to do it, but you can create a decorator that does this.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

x_data = np.arange(10)
y_data = 5*np.exp(-1.2*x_data) - 0.4 + rng.random(size=(len(x_data)))-0.5

def residual_monitor(y):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if result.shape == y.shape:
                residual = np.sum((y - result)**2)
                print(f"Residual: {residual}")
            return result
        return wrapped
    return decorator

@residual_monitor(y_data)
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c


guess = [1, 1, 1]
popt, cov = curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data, p0=guess)

x = np.linspace(x_data.min(), x_data.max(), 100)
y = f(x, *popt)
```

Output:

```py
Residual: 21.93056649410895
Residual: 21.93056649410895
Residual: 21.93056649410895
...
Residual: 0.8082138858016964
Residual: 0.8082138858048424
Residual: 0.8082138823699341
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you. However, I would also like to know the parameters which were chosen for each residual.

Comment: Never mind. I just had to add the 'args' in the print statement. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I think this shows the residual at every function call rather than at the end of every iteration of the solver.  I'm not sure but I think some solvers make multiple function calls per iteration.

Comment: @Bill That's correct. I don't think there is a way to get the residuals of the iterations.